# Google Sheets API set formatting using batchUpdate not working

Tags: google-sheets-api

I created a spreadsheet with data using google sheets api, after which I am trying to set formatting for the columns. I used the format specified in the api docs. The response gives me no error but the format for the data is not getting set

Below is my code:

```
const setFormattingGS = async (spreadSheetId, columnTypes, token, tabId) => {
  const formatDetails = [];
 columnTypes.forEach((key, ind) => {
    formatDetails.push({
      repeatCell: {
        range: {
          sheetId: tabId,
          startRowIndex: 1, // skip header
          // endRowIndex: 10, // all rows
          startColumnIndex: ind,
          endColumnIndex: ind + 1,
        },
        cell: {
          userEnteredFormat: {
            numberFormat: {
              type: key,
            },
          },
        },
        fields: "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat",
      },
    });
  });
  console.log(formatDetails);
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ requests: formatDetails }),
  };
  try {
    const formatApi = await fetch(
      `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${spreadSheetId}:batchUpdate`,
      options
    );
    const formatRes = await formatApi.json();
    return formatRes;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Format Column Error: ", error);
  }
};
```

I have ["TEXT", "NUMBER", "DATE"] in my column types
Below is the formatDetails Array I generated.

```
repeatCell: cell: userEnteredFormat: numberFormat: 
{type: 'TEXT'}
[[Prototype]]: Object 
[[Prototype]]: Object
fields: "userEnteredFormat.numberFormat"
range: 
endColumnIndex: 1
sheetId: 1274287844
startColumnIndex: 0
startRowIndex: 1
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

And this is the response from the API

```
{spreadsheetId: '1mQTykC8aCWJY1Y1nhhOIh9YuBJ-i2yvg0lCbA-X09Wc', replies: Array(3)}
replies: Array(2)
0 : {}
1: {}
2: {}
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
spreadsheetId: "1mQTykC8aCWJY1Y1nhhOIh9YuBJ-i2yvg0lCbA-X09Wc"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Please help me fix the issue. Thank you!

Comment: I think that your request is valid request with only the type. For example, when your request is run, the number format of cells "A2:A" is changed to text type. So, I cannot understand `not working`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to confirm your current issue.

Comment: I have tried your request and it is also working on my end. Can you provide a dummy sheet with the result you obtained from running your request?

Comment: Sorry I missed mentioning that it works for TEXT but not for NUMBER, CURRENCY. Apologies

Answer (score 0):

I missed "pattern" key value pair in numberFormat object. After I put the pattern it works perfectly. Thank you @Tanaike and @George for your time!